# Specific Path Algorithm with Speed Considered

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, timing

I need to create an algorithm where a "vehicle" covers a **1262 m** x **1262 m** area with **20%** overlap between each "leg".  The width of each leg is **103 m**, which by my calculations gives **16 "legs**" needed to cover this area.  At the end of each leg, the vehicle does a **180 degree** turn, and completes the next search leg.  The vehicle is traveling at a constant speed of **23** meters/second

Now the reason I am asking this on SO are some issues:

1. What is the best way to handle
   the "position" of vehicle in
   relation to the speed? Do take 1
   second "snapshots" and just move the
   vehicle 23 meters?  (This seems kind
   of rough around the edges)..
2. How do I handle the turns at the
   end of each leg with relation to the
   speed?
3. Should I preallocate the search
   leg parameters (IE find the bounds
   on each leg at initialization time)
   or dynamically calculate these at
   the end of each search leg?
4. I will be eventually
   implementing this algorithm in
   Java... What java
   functions/libraries will help me
   with the timing, math, etc?
5. What else do I need to consider?

**EDIT**

(Answering one of the responses)

Basically, there will be randomly placed "objects" throughout the search area that this needs to find... I was going to tackle that problem, once I got the vehicle going along the correct path and covering the area. The vehicle does cover area when it turns.. The minimum turn radius is 12 Meters.. I was just going to have it turn at the end of each search leg, and line up for the next leg

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to find the total time to complete all the legs + turns? Calculate the total distance? Or actually show a vehicle on screen moving about?

Comment: I need to simulate that the vehicle is "covering" the area at the given speed... I'm not sure if I will actually have a graphical display showing this..

Comment: Homework?  Or where will this be used?

Comment: Its homework, which is why I'm asking for "higher level" assistance with the timing, not specific details of implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look into search algortihms designed for looking for aerial or diving searches for lost people, planes, shipwrecks, etc.

Another idea is to look into the use of "space-filling curves".  Some of Bartholdi's work can be found [here](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~jjb/mow/mow.html).

Comment: Interesting historical and quantitative reading here on naval search patterns for U-boats

http://ormstomorrow.informs.org/archive/spring03/Submissions/carl_paper.pdf

Naval Research Logistics Quarterly should be a good journal for the military side of search patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Even though, I do not completly get the main idea behind your describe, I try to give some answers.

1. Take "snapshots" as small as possible. Stop time between calculations, and then move your vehicle according to the time. Example code below.
2. How many degrees does your vehicle turn per second?
3. If those dont change, I would calculate those in the beginning.
4. Pure Java SE should be enough for your needs. Check the API for java.lang.Math and java.lang.System.

---

```
while(true) {
     final long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
     doSomeCalculations();
     doSomethingMore();
     long passedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
     vehicle.move(26.0 / 1000.0 * passedTime);
}
```